# Using a document link in a workflow email

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I have a workflow that is copying a document to a folder. I am then emailing the user I selected on the initiation form and letting them know that the new document is available.

I would like to insert the link to the location where the document has been copied to into the email.

How do I get that location? Right now I am working in SharePoint Designer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the document name remains the same after copying to the new library- 
You can create a dynamic string variable to store the link like this: `<a href="http://site/targetLibrary/currentItem[FileLeafRef]">Document Title</a>`.
currentItem[FileLeafRef] is the dynamic part of the string which you will need to get from the current item.
FileLeafRef is the internal name of field "Name" in the document lib.

You can then use this variable in your email body.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the URL to be seen and clickable automatically in the email you click on "Add or Change Lookup" on the bottom left then for Data Source.

Then select `Current Item` and for Field from Source `Encoded Absolute URL`, then just press OK.